# How to convert a UUID string into UUID type

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, go, uuid

I have an array of string UUIDs that I want to change to UUID. Example of the data:

```
["69359037-9599-48e7-b8f2-48393c019135" "1d8a7307-b5f8-4686-b9dc-b752430abbd8"]
```

How can I change or parse it? I tried using `uuid.fromString()` method:

```
if len(a) == 2 {
    user1 := a[0]
    a[0], _ = uuid.FromString(a[0])
}
```

However, this gives me an error

> FromString returns UUID parsed from string input. Input is expected in
> a form accepted by UnmarshalText.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With [`github.com/gofrs/uuid/v5`](https://github.com/gofrs/uuid), use [`uuid.FromString`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofrs/uuid/v5#FromString).

> FromString returns UUID parsed from string input. Input is expected in a form accepted by UnmarshalText.

This method returns `UUID` or an `error` in case the parsing failed. You have two options to avoid explicit error handling:

- [`FromStringOrNil`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofrs/uuid/v5#FromStringOrNil), which returns only a `UUID`, but possibly `nil` in case of error
- [`Must`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofrs/uuid/v5#Must), which panics when the error of `FromString` is not `nil`. You use like:

```
uuid.Must(uuid.FromString("69359037-9599-48e7-b8f2-48393c019135"))
```

---

**WARNING: `satori/go.uuid`, the older popular UUID package, nowadays is unmaintained and has unfixed issues**. The package `gofrs/uuid` mentioned above is a maintained fork. From the package documentation:

> We recommend using v2.0.0+ of this package, as versions prior to 2.0.0 were created before our fork of the original package and have some known deficiencies.

---

With [`github.com/google/uuid`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid), use [`uuid.Parse`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#Parse). The rest of the pattern is the same as `satori/uuid`.

---

In your specific case, it looks like there's no problem in parsing the UUIDs, however the code you posted doesn't seem to produce the error you mention. Instead there is another problem:

`a[0], _ = uuid.FromString(a[0])`

you are attempting to reassign the value of `uuid.FromString`, which is a `UUID` to `a[0]` which is, presumably, a `string`.

The following code works fine (see it on [Go Play](https://go.dev/play/p/GTwa8tjr4MT)):

```
var a = []string{"69359037-9599-48e7-b8f2-48393c019135", "1d8a7307-b5f8-4686-b9dc-b752430abbd8"}

func main() {

if len(a) == 2 {
        user1 := a[0]
        s, _ := uuid.FromString(a[0])

        fmt.Println(user1) // prints 69359037-9599-48e7-b8f2-48393c019135
        fmt.Println(s) // prints 69359037-9599-48e7-b8f2-48393c019135
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `github.com/google/uuid` use the function

`func Parse(s string) (UUID, error)`

You also can use `func MustParse(s string) UUI` which auto-panics in case of an error.

See the docs for details: [uuid package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#UUID)